# Getting the date 1 month from today, UTC, in seconds, as a long. C#

Tags: c#, date

**Problem:** I am trying to get this date: A C# long that is timestamp(UTC) in seconds for one month from today.

I have tried several things including:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);
long nextMonth = startDate.Ticks;
```

I have seen the above in answers on converting DateTime to long, but the API I am using requires seconds (not ticks). I am hoping there is a more elegant solution than converting this long now from ticks to seconds via some sort of math like I've seen:

```
    long epoch = value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
```

But, even if there's not, I am not exactly sure how to convert from ticks to seconds. Thank you.

Comment: "long that is timestamp(UTC) in seconds" - not very clear what you need here. Unix filetime or Javascript time are possible interpretations of this... but "seconds" alone can't represent timestamp - it can only represent duration, so please [edit] post to clarify if you are looking for duration of a month in second, number of seconds from some date or something totally diffferent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with ticks or a complicated conversion at all? You need seconds right? Well it's just the number of TimeSpan.TotalSeconds between two separate dates.

```
 var startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
 var nextMonth = startDate.AddMonths(1);
 var duration = nextMonth - startDate;
 var value = duration.TotalSeconds;
```

value is a double. You can convert to long if needed with

```
var longValue = Convert.ToInt64(duration.TotalSeconds);
```

I wouldn't worry about it the loss in resolution.. It will be a sub-second loss no matter what dates you use. Which will happen no matter what hoops you jump through to convert, since your API resolution is limited to seconds.

Edited: If you need to Round... you can investigate the various rounding strategies.

Comment: Unless he really needs to floor round (seen it).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just getting the number of seconds in a single month (the duration of one month from now), the result will always be the number of seconds in the current month. So all we have to do is create a `TimeSpan` based on the number of days in the current month and get the `TotalSeconds` from that:

```
long seconds = (long) TimeSpan
    .FromDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month))
    .TotalSeconds;
```